# is there a way to run bitcoin-qt and point it to a local testnet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, testnet, bitcoin-qt-setup, local

I'm running a small testnet locally with this project:

http://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

but I'm having trouble pointing bitcoin-qt to the blockchain that I created locally myself, so I have some data like this:

```
bitcoin-cli -datadir=1  getinfo
{    
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 0.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1413617762,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
bitcoin-cli -datadir=2  getinfo
{
    "version" : 90300,
    "protocolversion" : 70002,
    "walletversion" : 60000,
    "balance" : 0.00000000,
    "blocks" : 0,
    "timeoffset" : 0,
    "connections" : 1,
    "proxy" : "",
    "difficulty" : 0.00000000,
    "testnet" : false,
    "keypoololdest" : 1413617762,
    "keypoolsize" : 101,
    "paytxfee" : 0.00000000,
    "relayfee" : 0.00001000,
    "errors" : ""
}
```

and I want that to be the data, and the addresses that is picked up and incorporated by bitcoin-qt. I guess there should be some flags to facilitate this but everything I've tried so far always in unsuccessful- maybe someone on here knows or has some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Makefile

start:
    $(BITCOIND) $(B1) -daemon
    $(BITCOIND) $(B2) -daemon

start-gui:
    $(BITCOINGUI) $(B1) &
    $(BITCOINGUI) $(B2) &

so probably ***make start-gui*** will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-testnet` option. This will run the daemon in testnet.

Comment: I think that will run it for the global testnet- isn't that right? I want to just run it on my own *local* testnet- I think it's different

Comment: They're the same thing. The way testnet-in-a-box prevents connecting to the global testnet is by connecting only to each other. Essentially, your daemon thinks you have the longest chain because it doesn't see the global testnet.